# Javascript array value display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax and the output is an array. I want to break it and display these value in their respective input field by the use of `inner.HTML` function.  Please let me know how can I break it or any function in jQuery so that I could display it in html.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Phone1] => 567567
        [LastName] => Amuso
        [Country] => Australia
        [City] => Sylvania
        [PostalCode2] => 228724
        [PostalCode] => 2227684
        [Email] => fabiauso@hotmail.com
        [State] => NSW
        [City2] => Sylvania
        [Country2] => Australia
        [FirstName] => Fabian
        [Id] => 78979
        [StreetAddress1] => 2/20 Evelyn St
        [Address2Street1] => 2/20 Evelyn St
    )

)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Kinda hoping those aren't some guy's real contact details...

Answer (score 2):

```
var myObject = <?php echo json_encode(myArray[0]); ?>;
console.log(myObject.Phone1);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [`json_enocde`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the array in PHP, then you can use jQuery's [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function to parse it in Javascript.

```
var arr = $.parseJSON( response );

$( arr[0] ).each( function( i, value ) {
    $( "input[name=" + i + "]" ).val( value );
});
```